# Main menu toolbar missing in PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, toolbar

I want to show the top main menu toolbar that recently disappeared in PyCharm.

[image: Screenshot of top toolbar]

I was trying to find the setting in `config\options\ui.lnf.xml` in the IntelliJIdea and PyCharm directories, but there is no such file.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work:

- press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice (equivalent to `Navigate` > `Search Everywhere`).
- type `main menu` (or just `ma me`).
- select `View | Appearance: Main Menu`.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to unhide (Or show back) the main menu/Toolbar in Goland/PyCharm or other IntelliJ Editors:

1. Click on the search icon in the top right-hand corner
2. In the search bar, type the word menu
3. You should see this result come up: View | Appearance: Main Menu
4. Then just click the toggle to change it from "Off" to "On"

[image: screenshot of editor window]

Comment: I can't find this option on GoLand 2021.3.3
Build #GO-213.6777.51, built on January 27, 2022

Answer (score 1):

Is your OS Linux? Try adding `linux.native.menu=false` into [Help | Edit Custom Properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) and restart IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file name `ui.lnf.xml`, the location of this file may different from OS to OS.

In Linux - the file location is - Home directory after that `.config/JetBrains/Idea_<<version>>/options`.
For example I am using Ubutu where I can find the location like -

```bash
$ sudo find /home/ -name "ui.lnf.xml"
/home/xxxx/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.2/options/ui.lnf.xml
```

Under the `ui.lnf.xml` there will be an entry if main menu is off:

```xml
<application>
  <component name="UISettings">        
    <option name="SHOW_MAIN_MENU" value="false" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Need to change the value from `false` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` > `Appearance` > `Show main menu in a separate toolbar`

[image]