# The main menu in 2023 versions of PyCharm CE is missing

Tags: linux, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, kde-plasma, arch

In newer versions of PyCharm (versions that include the New UI) I cannot get the Main Menu to show when using the Classic UI. I have restarted the IDE multiple times, tried multiple versions and searched StackOverflow for a solution. My OS is Arch Linux and I'm on KDE Plasma.

I have tried all of the suggestions from this post: [Pycharm show toolbar, main menu missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330843/pycharm-show-toolbar-main-menu-)

1. Suggestion: Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice, Navigate > Search. Type main menu, change 'show main menu in a separate toolbar to ON'

   - Result: No changes in UI
2. Suggestion: add `linux.native.menu=false` into Help

   - Result: the 'Help' menu is part of the Main Menu which I cannot access
3. Suggestion: make change to `ui.lnf.xml`

   - Result in one version of PyCharm, this had no effect.
   - In the newest version, this caused PyCharm to no longer open.

   > Error: CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
   > IDE is being shut down

Other things I've tried: (re)moving my JetBrains directory in `.config` and restarting the IDE.

Comment: This seems like something you should ask JetBrains tech support.

Comment: Suggestion 1 worked for me last time I needed this, I'm on Windows so this might be OS specific for you.